# How to create a class that has a property of another class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am creating a web application that has a Competitor, hence the class `Competitor`, and a poll that will join 2 `Competitor`s, hence the class `VotingPoll`. Here are the classes in JS:

```js
export class Competitor {
    constructor(_id, _name, easy, hard, tematicas, random_score, min1, min2, deluxe, replica) {
        this._id = _id;
        this._name = _name;
        this.easy = easy;
        this.hard = hard;
        this.tematicas = tematicas;
        this.random_score = random_score;
        this.min1 = min1;
        this.min2 = min2;
        this.deluxe = deluxe;
        this.replica = replica;
    }
    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    get_sum(mode) {
        if (mode === '_name' || mode === '_id') {
            throw new Error("mode can't be equal to 'name' nor 'id'");
        }
        let i = 0;
        this[mode].forEach((j) => {
            if (j !== 9) {
                i += j;
            }
        });
        return i;
    }
    get_total() {
        return (this.get_sum('easy') +
            this.get_sum('hard') +
            this.get_sum('tematicas') +
            this.get_sum('random_score') +
            this.get_sum('min1') +
            this.get_sum('min2') +
            this.get_sum('deluxe'));
    }
    serialize() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            id: this._id,
            name: this._name,
            easy: this.easy,
            hard: this.hard,
            tematicas: this.tematicas,
            random_score: this.random_score,
            min1: this.min1,
            min2: this.min2,
            deluxe: this.deluxe,
            replica: this.replica,
        });
    }
    static unserialize(data) {
        const newData = JSON.parse(data);
        return new Competitor(newData.id, newData.name, newData.easy, newData.hard, newData.tematicas, newData.random_score, newData.min1, newData.min2, newData.deluxe, newData.replica);
    }
}
export class VotingPoll {
    constructor(_id, comp_1, comp_2) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.comp_1 = comp_1;
        this.comp_2 = comp_2;
    }
    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
    get_winner(replica = false) {
        const comp_1 = this.comp_1;
        const comp_2 = this.comp_2;
        // Case replica
        if (replica) {
            if (comp_1.get_sum('replica') === comp_2.get_sum('replica') ||
                Math.abs(comp_1.get_sum('replica') - comp_2.get_sum('replica')) < 6) {
                return 'Réplica';
            }
            const max_num = Math.max(comp_1.get_sum('replica'), comp_2.get_sum('replica'));
            return max_num === comp_1.get_sum('replica') ? comp_1.name : comp_2.name;
        }
        // Normal case
        if (comp_1.get_total() === comp_2.get_total() || Math.abs(comp_1.get_total() - comp_2.get_total()) < 6) {
            return 'Réplica';
        }
        const max_num = Math.max(comp_1.get_total(), comp_2.get_total());
        return max_num === comp_1.get_total() ? comp_1.name : comp_2.name;
    }
    serialize() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            id: this._id,
            comp_1: this.comp_1,
            comp_2: this.comp_2,
        });
    }
    static unserialize(data) {
        const newData = JSON.parse(data);
        return new VotingPoll(newData.id, newData.comp_1, newData.comp_2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when calling `poll.get_winner()`, JS doesn't know that `comp_1` and `comp_2` are of type `Competitor`, and that they do have the function `get_total()`. Consequently, I get an error that says:

```js
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: comp_1.get_total is not a function
    at VotingPoll.get_winner (classes.ts:111)
    at fillTable (end.ts:35)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (add_listeners.ts:25)
```

If anyones have any idea on how to do this, or if you have another approach, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems not to be typescript code. General you can give the type after a *:* e.g. `const c: Competitor = new Competitior()`. Do it for all variables and you should be fine

Comment: That is the compiled JavaScript, that was previously TypeScript @Buntel, I am using `const comp_1: Competitor = new Competitor()`

Comment: Can you add your typescript code then and a complete example of the code?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE where the issue you are asking about and only the issue you are asking about is present. In particular, if your issue has to do with TypeScript, then you should include the TypeScript code. Since your issue is happening at runtime, then you should include also the code that actually makes a `new VotingPoll(...)` because apparently it is in error. Note that TypeScript does not exist at runtime; it only provides safety for TypeScript code.